# Can't connect my Nexus5 on OSx Yosemite

Tags: android, macos, usb, osx-yosemite

I can't really connect my Nexus 5 (Marshmallow) to my MacBookPro (OSx Yosemite).
This is what I tried:

1. Installing Android file transfer
2. Change USB cable
3. Activate the "USB Debug" option from the developer menu
4. Connect as MTP Device and/or PTP

None of the above has worked. If I run the `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` command from the shell, I can see there's no usb device attached. It's like my Mac don't even see the device. The only thing it does is to recharge the phone.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: That sounds like you are using the wrong type of cable. There are cables that just charge the device and there are others that are capable of data transfer

Comment: I'm using the original cable provided with the phone. I works on Windows

Comment: I meant "it" works on window

Answer (score 11):

Had the same problem, finally found the fix here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/3nnkaa/cant_access_android_device_internal_storage_from/

1. Open Settings
2. Enable Developer options:

   - Go to About phone (or tablet)
   - Scroll to the bottom
   - Tap Build number repeatedly. After several taps you will see it count down and then say "You are now a developer!"
3. Back to Settings
4. Tap Developer options, near the bottom
5. Scroll down to and tap Select USB Configuration
6. Change it to Charging only
7. Tap Select USB Configuration again
8. Change it back to MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)

Comment: P.S. This isn't even working for me on El Capitan, with Android File Transfer just re-installed, and toggling my Nexus 5X with 6.0(+?) on there between the 3 options, including PTP.

Comment: Had to use Airdroid, and I prefer the web interface vs. the desktop app, since it has a file manager.